# Set screen resolution in .Net

Tags: .net, pinvoke, screen

Does anybody know if there is any library of managed wrappers that allows me to set screen resolution so that I don't have to do the p/invoke stuff myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a post that looks like it might work: http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/faqs/?id=setscreenresolution&lang=en

Here's a second sample from: [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csdynamicscrres.aspx)